# How to get the full path from Outlook message/email search results

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I get the folder name shown in the search results in Outlook 365 (connected to an exchange server). But it's just the name of the folder without any hint where exactly it's located.

I found several solutions ([eg. here](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/846): open email from search, and go through Crtl+Shift+F again to get the folder path) but none of them seem to work with the current Outlook 365 version any more. Is there any new way through the GUI which can achieve that goal (without using VBA)?

**Note**: I can access the the full path using VBA (check my own answer [below](https://superuser.com/a/1692974/201818)), but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sadly, there is now way I know of and I have numerous "same" folders across 10 archives.  Thank you for the VBA link. I have made a note and may test it. It says we have to open the email before running the macro which is an impediment.

Comment: The VBA version works fine, I use it myself and it's great. I just need s.th. simple to distribute it in a domain environment...  too complicated with VBA (not counting various security risks) - hence my question.

Comment: What version of the desktop app do you use? It seems the Alt+Enter is still working fine (at least on my side). Mine Outlook 365 version 2111 build 14701.20226.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I didn't notice a solution using Alt+Enter, which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Full path? Probably not possible without VBA.

**GUI** way to find the path in older Outlook:

- Open the email
- Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, hit <kbd>F</kbd>
- Click <kbd>Browse</kbd> in the dialog that opens (or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on keyboard)
- Inspect the content of the new dialog.

*From memory... which is flaky at times, this is stored in muscle memory*

Comment: That is **exactly** the solution which I linked to, which doesn't work!

Comment: (but thanks for the try anyway)

Comment: =)  Well, that is the _level_ of "Outlook", in many ways. Been using that for years, looking for better ways all the time.

Comment: which version are you using, is it the app or the msi installation?

Comment: "MS.O. Pro Plus 2013"

Comment: ah, thats why... ;)

Answer (score 0):

So far the only working solution I found was getting the path through VBA, which I based off a solution I found at [vboffice.net](http://vboffice.net/en/developers/get-the-message-folder/), :

```
Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()

  'Declare/Init Variables
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim strMsg as String
  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow

  'Fetch Path
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
      Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
    Else
      Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
    End If
  Set F = obj.Parent

  'Show path and optionally open it:
  strMsg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf & "Switch to the folder?"
  If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
    End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: on a side note, is `based off` the right wording or should it be `based on`?